# Topic scope of "Robotics"

Tags: discussion

I can not find the description of the topic scope of "Robotics".

I would like to know I can ask questions about how to code XYZ for Pepper and things like that. I saw most of the Pepper questions are on stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The scope of Robotics is defined in the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in the [Help Centre](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help).

As it says there:

> Generic programming questions with no relation to robotics should be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

and

> if your question is directly related to *robotics* then even if your question might *also* be appropriate on another site, we are likely to be happy to see it here.

However, as it says in one of our off-topic close reasons

> Even questions which are on-topic here may still receive quicker and better answer on a more appropriate stack exchange site.

So it is up to you whether you ask *pepper* programming questions here or on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) (see the [pepper tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pepper)), the only thing we ask is that you don't ask in both places.

> [cross-posting the same question to multiple sites is not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/138432). If you find a better place to ask your question, please do not just ask your question a second time, instead flag it to a moderator who can migrate the question for you. Questions which are not considered on topic on the target site will have their migration rejected.

Note that *pepper* questions not related to programming would be off-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), but would be on-topic here.

To reflect the fact that we already have some *pepper* questions, I have created a [pepper](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pepper) tag here and re-tagged the questions I found to make them easier for others to find.