# Should we seed this community to boost activity?

Tags: discussion

The activity in this community seems to have plateaued somewhat since its start [five years ago](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics). [Seeding](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/what-is-a-seeded-question) this site at this stage may initially appear odd, but it could stimulate growth, define the edges of [what this site's topics are](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/topic-scope-of-robotics), and answer some common questions with a sense of generality in mind. This may help drive more people to this community (although I do see the number of users increasing by a few every day).

Questions:

> 1. Are my assumptions on seeding the site unreasonable?
> 2. Is there a problem with seeding *any* site?
> 3. Is there a problem with seeding *this* site at this stage?

Bonus Question:

> If seeding the site is acceptable, how do we decide what topics to target?

Comment: I think its acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we are way past the need for *Seeding*. As the term is normally used,  it is primarily about getting a site ready for the transition from *private* to *public* beta, which as you say was over five years ago.

Having said that, there has never been anything wrong with asking and answering a question yourself, especially if you know other people would find the answers useful.

As long a question is [on-topic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for *Robotics*, it is welcome here. Plus, who knows someone else might be able to provide a better answer than your own, and then you've learnt something too. *8')

At this point in the *Robotics* site lifecycle, scope is defined more than anything else by the corpus of questions already on our site, which is why repairing [broken windows](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-broken-window-theory/) is important. Every off-topic question is an invitation for another off-topic question to be asked.

So one way to help our community grow is to help keep the quality of our site high, and keep an eye out for low quality content so that it can be removed or fixed.

Anyone with [cast close and reopen votes privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can directly contribute to defining the edges of our site scope, and you really don't need much reputation to [flag posts](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) and contribute indirectly.